# Disable SSL on Website Local Backup for Local Editing in WAMP stack

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl, joomla, wamp

I have taken a backup of my Web server.

Database restored fine and looks like backup connection is also working.

I have problem with SSL, as I do not have any SSL on local Desktop, I seems not getting through the https to http.

As soon as I try to open http:\localhost\myBackupFolder\ it automatically goes to https:\localhost\myBackupFolder\

I have deleted .htaccess, ,htaccess.txt, php.ini, still it is getting routed to https.

Please Note* (The Backup was of a joomla site and forced site ssl was enable, but that doesn't looks like a problem at the moment. As a proof I had a sub-site folder containing HTML site, even that is getting routed to https)

Comment: `joomla and forced site ssl was enable` Why wouldn't that be a problem? If you have removed all redirects from Apache, it sounds like code is handling the redirect. Did you try and turn that off?

Comment: Well, I said tha because my simple HTML site inside that folder was not working. I have removed the ,htacess and php.ini from the cpanel backup I took, not from the WAMP stack. Can you please let me know how to remove redirect?

Comment: I've also changed the force_ssl to 0 in configuration.php, still it is going to https

Comment: Intersting, I can see ackend without SSL, problem is only to see front end

Comment: clear you cache. It might be cached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution

1. in joomla 'configuration.php', `Set public $force_ssl = '0';`
2. if required remove the livesite name, `public $live_site = '';`
3. Restart Your WAMP apache Server.

howver you may get a warning in local WAMP copy like:
Strict standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in C:\wamp\www..in line #45 but  One can deisale it by setting display_errors = Off in php.ini